# wkhtmltopdf not displaying footer on PDF

Tags: go, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf library to generate PDF and I cannot get the footer on the PDF doc when it is hosted on the server. It works properly on my local system. I am using below code to set the footer.

```
func HTMLtoPDF(html string, someID int64, templatePath string) (*wkhtml.PDFGenerator, error) {
pdfg, err := wkhtml.NewPDFGenerator()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
page := wkhtml.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(util.FilterSmartQuotesEtc(html)))
tempPath := path.Clean(fmt.Sprintf("%v/%s", templatePath, "footer.html"))
footerFilePath, err := getFooterFilePath(tempPath, someID)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
page.FooterHTML.Set(footerFilePath)

pdfg.AddPage(page)
pdfg.MarginTop.Set(10)
pdfg.MarginBottom.Set(10)

// Create PDF document in internal buffer
err = pdfg.Create()

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return pdfg, nil
}

func getFooterFilePath(templatePath string, someID int64) (string, error) {
tmpl, err := htmlTemplate.ParseFiles(templatePath)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

var buf bytes.Buffer
data := FooterData {
    SomeID: someID,
}
err = tmpl.Execute(&buf, data)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

// Save the rendered HTML to a temporary file
tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "footer-*.html")
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

if _, err := tmpFile.Write(buf.Bytes()); err != nil {
    return "", err
}
if err := tmpFile.Close(); err != nil {
    return "", err
}
return tmpFile.Name(), nil
}
```

I have verfied that the temp footer file is getting created inside getFooterFilePath  function and my someID variable is also substituted. I checked this by logging the generated temp footer file and I can see the content in the logs.
Am I doing anything wrong? Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you run `strace` on the server? It helps to find out the exact arguments passed to the wkhtmltopdf command. And since the footer is a file in the disk, `strace` will reveal IO errors too (if any). And please check the stderr from the command, maybe it contains something helpful too. See [(*PDFGenerator).SetStderr](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf#PDFGenerator.SetStderr) if you use this package.

Answer (score 1):

`wkhtmltopdf` has the `--replace <name> <value>` option to replace `name` with `value` in header and footer (repeatable). This is the recommended way to create a dynamic header and footer. Hopefully it will workaround the issue. Reference: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt.

Here is the demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    wkhtml "github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf"
)

func HTMLtoPDF(html string, someID int64) (*wkhtml.PDFGenerator, error) {
    pdfg, err := wkhtml.NewPDFGenerator()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    page := wkhtml.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(html))

    page.FooterHTML.Set("footer.html")

    // the following parameters are passed to footer.html in the query.
    page.Replace.Set("hello", "world")
    page.Replace.Set("my_id", strconv.Itoa(int(someID)))

    pdfg.AddPage(page)
    pdfg.MarginTop.Set(10)
    pdfg.MarginBottom.Set(10)

    err = pdfg.Create()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return pdfg, nil
}

func main() {
    pdfg, err := HTMLtoPDF(html, 123457789)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = os.WriteFile("temp.pdf", pdfg.Bytes(), 0o644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

var html = `
<html>
    <body style="font-size:100pt;">
        Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
`
```

And here is the **footer.html** file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function subst() {
        var vars = {};
        var query_strings_from_url = document.location.search
          .substring(1)
          .split('&');
        for (var query_string in query_strings_from_url) {
          if (query_strings_from_url.hasOwnProperty(query_string)) {
            var temp_var = query_strings_from_url[query_string].split('=', 2);
            vars[temp_var[0]] = decodeURI(temp_var[1]);
          }
        }
        var css_selector_classes = [
          // these values are provided by wkhtmltopdf.
          'page',
          'frompage',
          'topage',
          'webpage',
          'section',
          'subsection',
          'date',
          'isodate',
          'time',
          'title',
          'doctitle',
          'sitepage',
          'sitepages',

          // these values are provided by the "replace" option.
          'hello',
          'my_id',
        ];
        for (var css_class in css_selector_classes) {
          if (css_selector_classes.hasOwnProperty(css_class)) {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName(
              css_selector_classes[css_class]
            );
            for (var j = 0; j < element.length; ++j) {
              element[j].textContent = vars[css_selector_classes[css_class]];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="border: 0; margin: 0" onload="subst()">
    <table style="border-top: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="section"></td>
        <td class="hello"></td>
        <td class="my_id"></td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
          Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

If the above approach does not work or you're interested in finding out what's wrong with the temp file approach, we can do these things to narrow down the issue first:

1. run `strace -f /path/to/the/app > log.txt` to trace system calls and signals. The `-f` option makes it trace child processes (`wkhtmltopdf` is run in a child process).
2. the log from the last step should contains the options passed to the `wkhtmltopdf` command. Run the `wkhtmltopdf` command with the same options directly, see if it makes any difference.

   1. if the footer is rendered correctly, then there is something wrong in the Go code. It could be the temp file is not ready for use yet.
   2. if it does not make any difference, since the same command works in your local machine, this could be an issue related to the environment. Maybe the version of `wkhtmltopdf` on the server is buggy; maybe the server does not have the required fonts.

Please provide `log.txt` and the result of running `wkhtmltopdf` directly, so that we can decide what to do next.